# I want to print a multidimensional char array on an lcd in c51 (Keil)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, lcd, keil, c51

(The array is intialised with a bunch of characters)

I'm also getting an error saying "Data segment too large" when I make the array bigger. How do I copy the array from "CODE" to "XDATA"? or is this not the problem?

EDIT: Also when I call the function this way, the lcd skips element [i] [] in the array and prints the next element [i].

Any help I would very much appreciate.

```
  unsigned char piece [4] [8];   
  lcd_msg_write(piece[0]);  //rank     
  lcd_write(SecondLine);    
  lcd_msg_write(piece[1]);    
  lcd_write(SecondLine);    
  lcd_msg_write(piece[2]);  
  lcd_write(SecondLine);    
  lcd_msg_write(piece[3]);    
  lcd_write(SecondLine);

void lcd_msg_write(char * ptr2) 
{ 
   int x; 
   RS = 1;    
   for (x=0; x<8;x++)    
        lcd_write(*ptr2++);    //write till end of string reached 
   RS = 0;   
}

void lcd_write(unsigned char display_data)//LCD 1 {    
   EN = 1;    
   P0 = display_data;    
   EN = 0;    
   delay_5msec();   //delay to allow write operation to complete    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a variable to XDATA like this:

```
unsigned char xdata variable;
```

> EDIT: Also when I call the function this way, the lcd skips element [i] [] in the array and prints the next element [i].

If I understand it correctly, I suppose you have some value like 0 inside your array, that's why it can skip it. If you show the real output(in text form), I could tell you more information. But as for code correctness, everything is ok. It can also be a character table of LCD, so you write some incorrect character that LCD does not support or know.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem occurs due to char * ptr2.try unsigned char * in place of char *